# Mirrored HDD on Windows 2000 Server become invalid on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sata, windows-server-2000, hard-drive

I have a situation:

I had two SATA HDD, on mirror (soft mirrow by Windows), on Windows 2000 Advanced Server x86

then I remove it, throw away the server and keep the disk.

Now I want some data on it, so I put the HDD in a USB Sata encloser and put in my Windows 7 Ultimate x64. It found the disk but shown as Dynamic Disk, invalid.

Please advice me how to get the data back? 
I tried reactivate the disk on windows disk management, but it says "cannot do it on invalid disk"

As least I have two disks with same data, so any advice ( even with some risk ) welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Disk Management, click Action and then click Rescan Disks. Right-click any disk marked Foreign, click Import Foreign Disks, and then follow the instructions.  If it does not appear as Foreign after a rescan, this will not work.  Note that you must have both disks installed or it will not work.

I have noticed in the past that windows did not allow me to create a raid volume on removable media USB drives, it usually required a permanant fixed disk.  If your USB to SATA gear does not appear as removable, it should be ok.

You may want to investigate some third party partition manager such as BootIt, although many of these don't offer all features for dynamic disks, such as converting back to a simple disk.

**Move Disks to Another Computer**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753750.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Its not marked as foreign. I will try the bootit tool

Comment: You may want to try asking this on SuperUser.com, those folks may have more experience with this.